# Dozer mapping from an interface

Tags: java, dozer

I'm implementing a fairly simple REST server in Java for performing CRUD operations. I want to keep database and web API models separated so there are basically two class hierarchies and I need some kind of a mapping between the two. So say I have a target class I want to map to:

```
public class Target {
    private int x;

    public Target() { }
    public int getX() { ... }
    public void setX(int x) { ... }
}
```

Now the caveat is that I don't have a concrete source class but rather an interface:

```
public interface Source {
    int x();
}
```

This is a limitation of the particular ORM mechanism I use - I only define interfaces that the ORM maps my database entities to.
I want to do a mapping from objects implementing the above interface `Source` to objects of the class `Target`. Dozer seems to be completely lost when seeing this and I get only a blank object without any fields mapped.
Is it possible to achieve this with Dozer or, preferably, in some other lightweight object mapping library?

Comment: Create concrete source class which implements Source interface given by your ORM.

Comment: I could do that but I still want to map from a source object of some unknown (proxy) class that implements the interface not the concrete class I create.